# Count number of occurences in columns and output as chart

Tags: google-sheets

I'm coaching a little league team and would like to keep track of how many times a player has played a certain position in a game. I have a table with the available positions as column headers and enter the name of the player who played at that position after each game.

Here is an [image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqzjU.png):

[image]

I'd like to output a chart or table where I can easily see how many times the players have played in the various positions.

How would I do this most efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Add a column on the left below your existing table, list all players names there (one row each) then use a COUNTIF formula (under `Pos A` and copied across and down), eg:

```
=countif(B$2:B$3,$A5)
```

[image: Table example]

Comment: The table starts in first cell of the spreadsheet, is that the info you need to provide an example?

Comment: Sorry pnuts but I dont understand how to do this. Very grateful for your help though! I'm pasting a screenshot of my spreadsheet above but not all rows are visible, the names continue down to line 51. Also, now they've played 4 games so the positions played in the next game will start on line 18, thus, the names in the leftmost column will be pushed down after every game